# Is there a way to find "similar" data in an Excel column? Note the data are not duplicates but similar and inconsistent

Tags: excel

I would like to take an exported CVS file of my banking withdrawals and simplify the purchase location data so that I can see how much I spend at each store annually.  The problem is that each purchase description can be slightly unique so I can't use "Find Duplicate".  An example would be something like this:

**Description                   Category        Amount**
AMZN Mktp US                    Category Pending    $xxx
Amazon Digital Services         Entertainment       $yyy
Amazon                          Shopping        $zzz

I have tried finding solutions via excel help but haven't had much luck